# How can you find and display the difference between two dates in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, datediff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

> <sub>Since there clearly isn't any good canonical question on the subject, and over 5000 duplicates, I fell a canonical on the subject is in order. Please tell me if you find a duplicate **with a good answer, detailing the steps and giving a correct, robust solution**.</sub>

Given two example dates:

1. 2012-11-30 17:03:30
2. 2012-12-21 00:00:00

How can I find the difference between the two, and display it correctly?

Desired output:

> 20 days 6 hours 56 minutes 30 seconds